# How to find thresholds/lower/upper limit for weather factors for species distribution modelling?

Tags: meta-analysis, ecology, threshold, meteorology

What's the best way to find an estimate of weather factors' thresholds/lower/upper limits for a response variable (in my case disease severity) in studies conducted under field conditions? I have managed to find out that disease severity increases with increasing rain & relative humidity & temperature  but I'm struggling to find a way to determine thresholds e.g., upper temperature limit, lower temperature etc, which will be incorporated into SDMs. Normally data on thresholds is determined from studies conducted in labs, so I'm not sure it's possible to determine threshold with my data. My response variable is continuous, proportional plant disease severity data & my predictors are weather factors (wind speed, temperature, humidity & rainfall). Plants were planted each year in naturally infested plots, disease severity was recorded by the end of each year, and plants were harvested. The same process was repeated for ten years. I have attached a screenshot of my data & GAM's fit. Thanks in advance for giving any input
enter image description here [image]

[image]